# Blank content at back-end module page between header and footer

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.2.4

I've purchased the MageBright Store Locator module (no word from them, also to other customers). Uploaded all the files. Flushed cache, logged out and back in.

First I had a 404 problem because the config.xml was written in an outdated way. Fixed this I guess. But now in the back-end it just shows a blank space between the menu and footer of the back-end. Log doesn't show anything either.

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-locator-extension-5.html (demo at bottom)

**Config.xml**:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magebright_Gmapstrlocator>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Magebright_Gmapstrlocator>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <gmapstrlocator>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Magebright_Gmapstrlocator</module>
                    <frontName>gmapstrlocator</frontName>
                </args>
            </gmapstrlocator>
        </routers>
    </frontend>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Magebright_Gmapstrlocator after="Mage_Adminhtml">Magebright_Gmapstrlocator</Magebright_Gmapstrlocator>
                    </modules>
                </args>
             </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

**System.xml**:

```
<config>
    <tabs>
        <magebright translate="label" module="gmapstrlocator">
            <label>Magebright Extensions</label>
            <sort_order>101</sort_order>
        </magebright>
    </tabs>
    <sections>

        <gmapstrlocator  translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
        <tab>magebright</tab>
        <label>Store Locator</label>
        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
        <sort_order>200</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>

             <general translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
                <label>General Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>                
                <identifier translate="label">
                    <label>Frontend Router</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </identifier>   
                <page_title translate="label">
                    <label>Meta Title</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <comment></comment>
                </page_title>
                <meta_description translate="label">
                    <label>Meta Description</label>
                    <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <comment></comment>
                </meta_description> 
                <meta_keywords translate="label">
                    <label>Meta Keywords</label>
                    <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <comment></comment>
                </meta_keywords>                
                <page_heading translate="label">
                    <label>Page Heading</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </page_heading>
                <page_subheading translate="label">
                    <label>Page Sub Heading</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </page_subheading>

                <standard_lat translate="label">
                    <label>Standard Latitude</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </standard_lat>             
                <standard_long translate="label">
                    <label>Standard Longitude</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </standard_long>
                </fields>
             </general>

             <manage_links translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
                <label>Links Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                <header_enable translate="label">
                    <label>Enable Header Link</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </header_enable>
                <header_text translate="label">
                    <label>Header Link Label</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>    
                    <depends><header_enable>1</header_enable></depends>
                </header_text>
                <footer_enable translate="label">
                    <label>Enable Footer Link</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>    
                </footer_enable>
                <footer_text translate="label">
                    <label>Footer Link Label</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store> 
                    <depends><footer_enable>1</footer_enable></depends>
                </footer_text>
                </fields>
             </manage_links>

             <layout_update translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
                <label>Layout Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>21</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                <page_column translate="label">
                    <label>Select Layout</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>gmapstrlocator/system_config_source_layoutupdate</source_model>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>    
                </page_column>              
                </fields>
             </layout_update>

             <manage_attribute translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
                <label>Attributes Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>22</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                <enable_filters translate="label">
                    <label>Enable Attributes Filter</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </enable_filters>       
                <filter_text translate="label">
                    <label>Attributes Filter Heading</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>                 
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <depends><enable_filters>1</enable_filters></depends>
                </filter_text>              
                </fields>
             </manage_attribute>

             <manage_search translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
                <label>Search Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>23</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                <product translate="label">
                    <label>Enable Search By Product</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </product>              
                <address translate="label">
                    <label>Enable Search By Address, Zip Code, State</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </address>              
                </fields>
             </manage_search>

             <info_popup translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
                <label>Map Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>24</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                <button_text translate="label">
                    <label>Get Direction Button Text</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </button_text>

                <marker_image translate="label">
                    <label>Map Marker</label>
                    <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
                    <backend_model>gmapstrlocator/system_config_backend_image_marker</backend_model>
                    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">gmapstrlocator/marker</base_url>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <comment>Allowed file types: PNG, GIF, JPEG</comment>
                </marker_image>

                <bg_primary_image translate="label">
                    <label>Mouse Hover Marker</label>
                    <frontend_type>image</frontend_type>
                    <backend_model>gmapstrlocator/system_config_backend_image_bgprimary</backend_model>
                    <base_url type="media" scope_info="1">gmapstrlocator/bgprimary</base_url>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <comment>Allowed file types: PNG, GIF, JPEG</comment>
                </bg_primary_image>

                <enable_mouseover_marker translate="label">
                    <label>Enable Mouse Hover Marker</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>                   
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </enable_mouseover_marker>

                <enable_marker_numbers translate="label">
                    <label>Enable Marker Numbers</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </enable_marker_numbers>

                <enable_sidebar_markers translate="label">
                    <label>Enable Sidebar Markers</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </enable_sidebar_markers>

                <map_zoom translate="label">
                    <label>Map Zoom</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>6</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <comment>Enter digit to set map zoom. For Ex.( 6, 8, 11)</comment>
                </map_zoom>
                <map_distance>
                    <label>Map Distance</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>gmapstrlocator/system_config_source_mapdistance</source_model>
                    <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>                    
                </map_distance>

                </fields>
             </info_popup>           
             <seo translate="label comment" module="gmapstrlocator">
                <label>Search Engine Optimizations</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>25</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <url_suffix translate="label">
                            <label>URL Suffix</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <comment>(eg: .html)</comment>
                </url_suffix>
                </fields>
            </seo>  

            <image_settings translate="label">
                <label>Store Image Settings</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>26</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                <fields>                        
                    <image_width translate="label">
                            <label>Image Width</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>                                
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </image_width>
                    <image_height translate="label">
                            <label>Image Height</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>                                
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </image_height>
                </fields>
            </image_settings>

        </groups>
        </gmapstrlocator>


    </sections>
</config>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

> First I had a 404 problem because the config.xml was written in an outdated way

If this means that initially the routes for admin were defined to start with their own module identifier instead of html, you need to change the layout handles also.
I mean if initially the url was `locator/adminhtml_something/here/` and now is `admin/locator_something/here/` you need to edit the admin layout file and change the layout handles from `locator_adminhtml_something_here` to `adminhtml_locator_something_here`.